Access the JSON property from JSON Response - Azure APIM Policies
If I am getting below JSON response from an API, how can I get the status and code properties in that.
{
  "error": {
    "status": 0,
    "code": "string",
    "message": "string",
    "target": "string",
    "instance": "string",
    "details": [
      "string"
    ]
  }
}

Below is my policy code which is currently in place.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="errorResponse" value="@(context.Response.Body.As<JObject>()["error"])" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables["errorResponse"]!=null)">
                <set-variable name="errorStatus" value="@{
                    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(context.Response.Body.As<JObject>()["error"]);
                    var value = (string)jsonObject["status"];
                    return value;
                }" />
                <set-variable name="errorStatus" value="@{
                    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(context.Response.Body.As<JObject>()["error"]);
                    var value = (string)jsonObject["code"];
                    return value;
                }" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@((int)context.Variables["errorStatus"]==404)">
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="200" reason="NotFound" />
                            <set-body template="liquid">
                                { 
                                    "status": "NotFound"
                                }
                            </set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </when>
                </choose>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>


I am expecting to get the value of status and code json properties from the outbound response.

If you need to access the status and code properties from the API response in your policy code, the following should work:
<set-variable name="ResponseBody" value="@(context.Response.Body?.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true))" />
<set-variable name="ErrorStatus" value="@{
    var responseBody = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<JObject>("ResponseBody");
    return (int)responseBody["error"]["status"];
}" />
<set-variable name="ErrorCode" value="@{
    var responseBody = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<JObject>("ResponseBody");
    return (string)responseBody["error"]["code"];
}" />


Thankyou so much, that code worked and has solved the issue :)
